# Why my website is showing junk characters?

Tags: 6, caching

My Drupal 6 website is showing junk characters like:

<�h�3�>�C�o�m�m�e�n�t�s�<�/�h�3�>� �<�t�a�b�l�e�>�<�t�r� �b�g�c�o�l�o�r�=�'�#�E�7�E�7�E�F�'�>�<�t�d�>�P�o�s�t�e�d� �O�n�:� �1�2�-�1�3�-�2�0�1�0�

It used to happen once in every 1-2 months, and with any page of the website. Clearing the cache resolve the problem.
I think its the problem with cache_page table and page compression, because when I manually clear the entry in cache_page table for that particular page, it gets resolved.

Comment: I have just removed the question marks to check what the code actually <h3>Comments></h3><table><tr bgcolor='#E7E7EF'><td>Posted On: 12-13-2010

Answer (score 1):

When we remove � manually, we see:

```
<h3>Comments</h3> <table><tr bgcolor='#E7E7EF'><td>Posted On: 12-13-2010
```

Probably it comes from [comment.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.tpl.php/6) in your theme. At first glance looks like UTF-8 - UTF-16 issue, but only you can really debug that.

The exact part of code you pasted seems to appear in following threads:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/76407
- https://www.drupal.org/node/28016

See, maybe original developer was using them? Hope it helps you with debugging, we here cen't really help more.